# Не показывается иконка на NW.JS (nodewebkit) приложении

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, icon, nwjs

## В чем проблема

Пишу игровой лаунчер на  NW.JS (v16.15.1), в окне приложения не отображает иконка

#### Окно

[image]

#### Панель задач

При этом конку nw.exe в каталоге и на панели задач я смог заменить с помощью утилиты Resource hacker, выглядит это вот так:
[image]

#### Package.json

До этих манипуляций была обычная иконка nw по стандарту, манифест файл выглядит так:
[image]

## Пути к иконкам

Путь к иконке пробовал вводить по разному! Все методы которые я пробовал:

.../.../common/icon.ico

../../common/icon.ico

..../common/icon.ico

.../common/icon.ico

../common/icon.ico

./common/icon.ico

/common/icon.ico

.../.../icon.ico

../../icon.ico

.../icon.ico

../icon.ico

./icon.ico

/icon.ico

icon.ico

Так-же пытался загружать иконки в формате jpg, png и даже перетаскивал из папки в /common в корневую папку где лежит .exe.
При открытии HTML файла main.html иконка показывается!  - В адресной строке работает! В package.json не работает.

Ещё пробовал вписывать параметр ( icon: "" ) рядом с title, потом внутри window: {}. Нигде не работает, уже не знаю что делать! Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

РЕШЕНО

Он принимает только иконки PNG формата. ICO, JPG, и тд. ОН НЕ ПРИНИМАЕТ!